# Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, installation

I am starting to learn android but havent been able to get anywhere. I downloaded android studio as per instructions and im trying to set up an AVD.
I am using a Mac Air(macOS High Sierra) with java 1.8.0_51.

The moment i launch an AVD there is a warning in the event log: 
"Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release."

The emulator just gets stuck on the loading page.

So far i have tried to :
1. Reduce AVD Ram size
2. Increase AVD heap size
3. change to "software" to avoid issues if any with my graphics card
4. Install/ delete many versions of phones/api levels for avd

In the Logcat logs i see the following errors:

> 03-09 17:27:15.544 0-1114/? I/lowmemorykiller: No kernel
>   memory.pressure_level support (errno=2) 03-09 17:27:15.545 0-1114/?
>   E/lowmemorykiller: Kernel does not support memory pressure events or
>   in-kernel low memory killer

.....

> 03-09 17:30:28.470 1122-1122/? I/iptables: iptables v1.4.20: can't
>   initialize iptables table 'nat': Table does not exist (do you need to
>   insmod?) 03-09 17:30:28.470 1122-1122/? I/iptables: Perhaps iptables
>   or your kernel needs to be upgraded. 03-09 17:30:28.470 1122-1122/?
>   I/iptables: iptables terminated by exit(3) 03-09 17:30:28.629
>   1122-1122/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables
>   -t nat -N oem_nat_pre  03-09 17:30:30.888 1122-1122/? I/iptables: iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table 'nat': Table does
>   not exist (do you need to insmod?) 03-09 17:30:30.888 1122-1122/?
>   I/iptables: Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
>   03-09 17:30:30.902 1122-1122/? I/iptables: iptables terminated by
>   exit(3) 03-09 17:30:31.112 1135-1135/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load
>   memtrack module (No such file or directory) 03-09 17:30:31.114
>   1135-1135/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   03-09 17:30:31.257 1122-1122/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for
>   /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j oem_nat_pre  03-09
>   17:30:35.605 1122-1122/? I/iptables: iptables v1.4.20: can't
>   initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to
>   insmod?) 03-09 17:30:35.607 1122-1122/? I/iptables: Perhaps iptables
>   or your kernel needs to be upgraded. 03-09 17:30:35.607 1122-1122/?
>   I/iptables: iptables terminated by exit(3)

....

Please let me know what i can do to fix this and get any emulator working!

Comment: I have filed this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122879698) in Google's _IssueTracker_.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be your CPU hardware. AVD Google API levels 21+ do not run well on CPUs that do not support [Extended Page Tables (EPT) and Unrestricted Guest (UG)](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/30) such as Core 2 Duo. Your best option is to try an system image with AVD Google API level <= 20 on those types of CPUs. You will still see this warning, but the emulator will boot up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plenty of memory and the problem still exists, install:

`Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` from Android Studio SDK Tools

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

I was suffering from same problem. I searched everywhere but i didn't get the solution. Then i knew that this problem is occurring only because of low RAM.

You can solve this problem by increasing the RAM. Because my laptop had 4 GB RAM and when the RAM increased the problem solved completely! Although i bought a new laptop with i5 8th gen.. It has 8gb RAM...