# Android Emulator keeps crashing on bootup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

After i have installed Android Studio and created an Project, the android emulator always crashes on opening.

The log says the following:

> 19:13 Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
>
> 19:13  Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

And i dont want to connect an physical device, just because i want it on an emulator.

When I run the AVD again, the same error occurs.
I really need help.

Note: I see the Android Emulator starting screen and after that, it closes itself.

Im running Windows 10.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem already. The issue was my CPU hardware. AVD Google API levels 21+ do not run well on CPUs that do not support [Extended Page Tables (EPT) and Unrestricted Guest (UG)](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/30#issuecomment-372544743) such as Intel Core 2 Duo. Getting an newer CPU solved the problem.