# Android Studio Emulator Errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I got an error message on android studio one of the error messages was

> "qemu system x86_64.exe has stopped working"

and the others were:

> 5:23 PM   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on
>   this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We
>   will address this in a future release.
>
> 5:23 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event
>   loop'. No response for 15001 ms
>
> 5:26 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819
>   (0xC0000005)

Can anyone guide me to any tutorials which will help me resolve the errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)