# Android Studio Emulator Not Showed

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I get Below Errors,

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration!
>
> Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this
>   machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will
>   address this in a future release.
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

But AVD is Created, and  Already Installed Intel hardware acceleration! and My API Level is 19. How to Resolved It.

Comment: does your PC support hardware acceleration?

Comment: yes i had already installed  " intelhaxm-android ".

Comment: windows or linux ??

Comment: also which CPU you have?

Comment: windows8.1 64 bit

Comment: check if you avd folder is there in android sdk > avd

Comment: wow Krystal awesome :D

Comment: `also which CPU you have?`

Comment: avd where is located in android sdk.

Comment: Are you finally going to tell me which CPU you have?

Comment: location  : `user>.android>avd>you_avd_name`, and `.folder` is sometimes hidden

Comment: I met same issues, and I download HAXM from [Intel official page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) instead of via android studio SDK manager.

Comment: MY CPU Is Intel pentium(R) CPU G3250 @3.20 GHZ 3.19GHZ

Comment: ya Already I have avd and My path is C:\Users\03t079\.android\avd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Enable virtualisation in your PC and try again if not previously done. 
Then go to AVD manager and from the dropdown list, select cold boot now.