# I installed intel HAXM and enabled virtual technologies in BIOS, but stil can`t run the emulator

Tags: android, emulation

Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

```
14:59   Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!

14:59   Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

14:59   Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

14:59   Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

14:59   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

14:59   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while Running Android Application - Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686324/error-while-running-android-application-could-not-initialize-opengles-emulatio)

Comment: The new android emulator needs Corei3 cpu or higher models according to HAXM documents

Comment: the issue here rather is, that there is no openGL driver available or installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)