# emulator stop and close before complete boot

Tags: android-emulator

my problem is the emulator in Android Studio stops a few seconds after I run it. the emulator is Nexus 4 API 25 with 768MB RAM.
in first time i start it in cold boot mode but it stop.

The error in EventLog is this:

10:14 PM    Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

10:14 PM    Emulator: none.xml:3: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected

10:14 PM    Emulator:

10:14 PM    Emulator: ^

10:14 PM    Emulator: none.xml:3: parser error : attributes construct error

10:14 PM    Emulator:

10:14 PM    Emulator: ^

10:14 PM    Emulator: none.xml:3: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 3

10:14 PM    Emulator:

10:14 PM    Emulator: ^

10:14 PM    Emulator: none.xml:3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

10:14 PM    Emulator:

10:14 PM    Emulator: ^

10:14 PM    Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error

10:14 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

i search too much about it but none of the solutions solved my problem.

VTx is enable and HAXM is installed up to date.

what can i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Comment: thnx, i'll check it