# Android Studio, emulator won't open

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting the following error message on Android studio:

Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

Is there a way to being up an emulator on this computer without having to purchase a new computer or attaching my mobile phone? It's a 64-bit Intel Sony Vaio computer.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a limitation with your hardware, and is not something that can be resolved with your current CPU.

However, this shouldn't interfere with your usage of the Android emulator, only the listed features (Quick Boot, Snapshots) should be affected.

Are you able to boot the Android emulator at all? If not, you will likely get a different error message than this one when trying to launch it.

Comment: What is EPT + UG. The Emulator won't open up at all. I can only run the code onto my smartphone attached to the USB port.

Comment: Again, this a limitation of the PHYSICAL HARDWARE of your computer. It seems that your CPU lacks certain required emulation features. There is nothing that can be done about that apart from buying a modern CPU.