# android emulator finished with exit code 0

Tags: android-studio

> 6:02 PM   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on
>   this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We
>   will address this in a future release.
>
> 6:02 PM   Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your
>   system. Reducing to maximum supported size 512M
>
> 6:02 PM   Emulator:
>   C:\Users\Reman\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll.
>
> 6:02 PM   Emulator:
>   C:\Users\Reman\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
>   failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented**
>
> 6:02 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

My specs:

**intel core 2 duo E7200(2.53GHz)**

**integrated 82945g intel graphics**
 and my CPU does not support hyper-threading technology and virtualization technology.

I have installed the emulator and is up to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199715/emulator-warning-quick-boot-snapshots-not-supported-on-this-machine)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

- Your *size on disk* is not full - this's often happen due to creation of some virtual devices that are unused
- The RAM size of emulator is not minimum as your requirements

One more thing that I personally use: [Use Pen Drive as a RAM](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Pen-Drive-As-RAM)

---

### Updated:

[Use HDD as RAM](http://tricksnow.com/how-to-use-hard-disk-as-ram-on-windows/)

> - Right Click on “This PC or My Computer” and Select Properties.
> - Now Click on “Advance System Settings”.
> - Now in “System Properties” you have to select “Advanced” tab.
> - Now click on “Settings” Under “Performance”.
> - Now in “Performance Option” again you have to select “Advanced” tab.
> - Now click on “change“ under “Virtual Memory”.
> - Un-check “Automatically manage paging file size of all drivers” and select “Custom size”.
> - In Custom Size enter the amount of data According to “Space available” which is written there.
> - Click on “set” button and Click on OK.
> - Now it will ask you to restart your Computer or Laptop.

---

Another work around steps (tested) :

1. Restart your Android Studio
2. Create new device in your AVD Manager
3. Increase the RAM size of the Emulator

Comment: tried both the methods but still the problem exists.